# Using Catch2 in Visual C++ 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, catch-unit-test

I'm trying to make a Unit Testing project using the Catch framework, but am faced with Link errors.

I've set up the project as follows:

1. Create a Native Unit Test project
2. Add Catch to the include directories
3. Add `#include <catch.hpp>` to stdafx.h
4. Write the following simple source file

unittest.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
namespace Catch2_Test
{
  TEST_CASE("Y U no work")
  {
    REQUIRE(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Some things: 1. Go read the catch tutorial. It shows you how to set things up. Somewhere you need to `#include <catch.hpp>` with a macro defined (I think it's `CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN`). This file would need to not use the precompiled header. 2. Don't use a Native Unit Test project for this; those projects are designed to be used with Visual Studio's unit testing library

Comment: @Justin I'm aware of that. I was following the Catch tutorial itself on how to integrate it into VC++ so that the Test Explorer could be used rather than the console.

Comment: @AryaPourtabatabaie AFAIK, that can't be done at the moment. [It's on the radar for the Visual Studio team, though](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/05/10/unit-testing-and-the-future-announcing-the-test-adapter-for-google-test/).

Comment: You've somehow mixed two issues up: using Catch in pre-compiled header, and, integrate Catch into Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had cloned Catch2 from the [master branch](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2), while the VS integration worked on a [branch off Catch](https://github.com/colonelsammy/Catch).

Comment: Please share the user survey that lead you to this conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

**For integrating Catch into Visual Studio**
refer the ACCU article [Integrating the Catch Test Framework into Visual Studio, by Malcolm Noyes](https://accu.org/index.php/journals/1851)

**For using Catch2 in pre-compiled headers**,
refer [Catch2 issue 1061](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/issues/1061), where *horenmar* gave an example. The changes have been released as part of v2.1.0

In summary, the solution given is:

```
// stdafx.h
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#define CATCH_CONFIG_ALL_PARTS
#include "catch.hpp"

// PCH-test.cpp:
#include "stdafx.h"

#undef TWOBLUECUBES_SINGLE_INCLUDE_CATCH_HPP_INCLUDED
#define CATCH_CONFIG_IMPL_ONLY
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "catch.hpp"

// tests1.cpp:
#include "stdafx.h"

TEST_CASE("FooBarBaz") {
    REQUIRE(1 == 2);
}
```

Comment: try integration in vs2017, Test Adapter for Catch2, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JohnnyHendriks.ext01

Comment: and resharper_ c++ can also recognize the catch2 test cases